# Interface drawing elements in Xcode 4 for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Maybe this is stupid, but are there any drawing elements in Xcode 4.2 ?
You know, like a basic frame with a border, or a line, or anything?

If I want a rectangle with a border, and I want to put some buttons "inside",
do I have to use views, and buttons, and labels, and Quartz to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes.  Xcode, and UI builder are all about making applications that look and feel like Mac or iPhone/iPod apps.  Using the tools makes it easier to do so, and harder to do otherwise.